# tar exiting with code 1 but no explanation

Tags: tar

I'm having a strange issue with `tar`. I'm running it in a `Dockerfile`, so while building an image. To make matters more complicated, this is using `buildx` on a buildserver to build an `arm64` image on an `amd64` machine, using qemu. So maybe those things are influencing the behavior I'm seeing.

But the core problem is, I'm downloading a `tgz` file, which seems to work fine. Then I do:

```
tar -xvf file.tgz
```

And I get the following error:

```
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Everywhere I search, there is an extra line explaining what exactly went wrong (e.g. it isn't a correct tar.gz file). But in my case, there is no extra line. Any ideas how I can investigate this further?

Comment: Apparently, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272380/error-docker-buildx-on-x86-64-for-building-multiarch-x86-64-arm64 (voted to close) and I should unzip and untar separately.

Comment: just a curiosity: which form of the RUN instruction did you use in your Dockerfile? The shell form or the exec form? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run

Comment: @jackdbd we're using the shell form

Answer (score 0):

This `tar` file is compressed so you can first uncompress it and then untar. Or you can do this with one command:

```
tar xzvf file.tgz
```

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't work. I really had to do it in 2 separate steps. No idea why.